# How do I upgrade all symbol packages?

Tags: package-management, bug-reporting, debug, apport

When submitting Apport reports to Launchpad, I regularly get the error "outdated debug symbol package" from the retracing service. How can I upgrade all debug symbol packages to the latest version? They don't seem to upgrade with regular updates through update-manager.

Comment: Can you give an example? I actually don't think that message is about a problem at your end. Also, when upgrading a package which has outdated -dbg(sym) packages installed, those would simply get removed.

Comment: Sure, here is an example (see the last message in the thread): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/824263

Comment: Hi, this does indicate that your system is not up-to-date. It's not just limited to the debug packages.

Comment: Thanks. I upgrade daily, but I guess if the retracer is slow, new updates will tend to appear since the report (and thus package data) was filed. It's just that this bug seemed to persist across the updates, so it's weird that the report had to be routinely tossed out.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade $(dpkg -l '*-dbg' | grep '^ii' | awk '{print $2}')
```

I think it can be do easier, but don't remember... Above will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ApportRetracingService](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApportRetracingService), it can be the retracing service that is outdated.